# Magento: Add to Cart adds alway double quantity, why?

Tags: javascript, magento

Call add to cart:
`<button title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="btn" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit();"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>`

JS Code that send the product to cart, but with double qty. It should qty 1 but in cart is qty 2.

```
 var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
    productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
        if (this.validator.validate()) {
            var form = this.form;
            var oldUrl = form.action;

            if (url) {
               form.action = url;
            }
            var e = null;
            try {
                this.form.submit();
            } catch (e) {
            }
            this.form.action = oldUrl;
            if (e) {
                throw e;
            }

            if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                button.disabled = true;
            }
        }
    }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
```

When I navigate to the add to cart form submit link directly, the qty is also double in the cart.
http://example.com/checkout/cart/add?product=55&qty=1 (adds double qty)

Comment: Your try catch seems messy, but I don't think that's the problem anyway..

Answer (score 2):

Try to change

```
onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit();"
```

with:

```
onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(); return false;"
```

or

```
onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"
```

Refer this link for more details: http://importantmagento.blogspot.in/2012/07/magento-fix-add-to-cart-button-adds.html

Comment: These variants I've already tried. Does not change the problem. :-(

Comment: Directly add to cart url adds also double qty.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `app/design/frontend/{theme}/default/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml`

Find ADD to Cart button and replace the code on on click event

```
onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(); return false;"
```